# Dynamically load Tabpages and data into those tabpages

Tags: vb.net

I ma new Learner. I am creating an application in Visual Basic and I need help to load dynamically data from database into my tabpages.

I want TabPages names to be "Category Names" (From Tbl_Category) and in each Tabpages i want buttons to be created and these buttons are each record from "Tbl_ItemDetails.

button name will be from "ItemSKU" column. and button image will be from "Item_Image" column.

i have searched a lot but couldn't do it. Please help me on this. 
if you guys know any other way of doing it (without tabpages) please share. Thanks!

here are some codes which i tried. 
1. image code is not working.
2. if i have more items on tabpages it does not show any scroll bar. so i can see only few button not all.
![enter image description here][1]

Private Sub AddProductsToTabbedPanel()

```
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    For Each tp As TabPage In TabControl1.TabPages
        Dim filteredProduct As ObjectQuery(Of Tbl_ItemDetails) = New ObjectQuery(Of Tbl_ItemDetails)(("SELECT VALUE P FROM Tbl_ItemDetails AS P WHERE P.CatID = " + i.ToString), cse)
        Dim flp As FlowLayoutPanel = New FlowLayoutPanel
        flp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        For Each tprod As Tbl_ItemDetails In filteredProduct
            Dim b As Button = New Button
            b.Size = New Size(100, 100)
            b.Text = tprod.ItemSKU

            ' ''how can i get image on button. bellow code is not working

            'b.BackgroundImage = tprod.Item_Image
            'b.Image = tprod.Item_Image



            b.Tag = tprod
            AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf Me.UpdateProductList
            flp.Controls.Add(b)

        Next
        tp.Controls.Add(flp)
        i = (i + 1)

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to seed your question title with languages etc - that is what the tags are for.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you could give us some code you have tried, we can point you in the right direction

Comment: Please post a screenshot or a couple as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1: How the Image will work

a) If you only provide a pathname to an existing file

```
  button.Image = New Bitmap("C:\temp\Info.bmp")
```

b) If you get a bytearray from your DB containing the bitmap

```
  Dim byteArrayFromDB As Byte()
  Dim memStream As System.IO.MemoryStream
  Dim img As Image

  memStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArrayFromDB)
  img = Image.FromStream(memStream)
```

### 2: Scrollable FlowLayoutPanel

```
 flp.AutoScroll = True
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. AutoScroll is working perfectly fine, but i am still stuck with image.

Comment: In what kind of format do you get the "image information"?<br/> Which datatype does the "Item_Image" have?

Comment: Item_Image datatype is Image here are my codes for saving image.

Comment: 'for Image Saving
                Dim ms As New MemoryStream
                ItemPictureBox.Image.Save(ms, ItemPictureBox.Image.RawFormat)
                Dim data As Byte() = ms.GetBuffer()
                Dim p As New SqlParameter("@LImage", SqlDbType.Image)
                p.Value = data
                CMD1.Parameters.Add(p)



                CMD1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                CMD1.Dispose()